# Text reference for linear Stark Effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, perturbation-theory

I was trying to study the linear stark effect and an example of the splitting of $2S\pm2P_z$ orbitals, described [here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Under_Construction/Book%3A_Quantum_Mechanics_(Fitzpatrick)/07%3A_Time-Independent_Perturbation_Theory/7.6%3A_Linear_Stark_Effect). Can someone suggest to me a reference for the similar material discussed but in some reliable place like some reputed text book or published papers?

Comment: Your link is contributed by Prof. Fitzpatrick of UT Austin. He is a reliable source of information.

Comment: @G.Smith I'm not disputing the reliability of Prof. Fitzpatrick here. I'm sorry if I sound that way. I want a textbook or paper reference because I want to cite it in my thesis. Generally, these websites don't guarantee that these posts will be there forever in their server. These posts can be removed sometimes. So I want to cite something which has a sense of permanence, i.e., reputed text books or research papers. Thank you!